# ternary operator for display image in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i want to display dummy image from folder when value is null. Mean when `ImageUrl='<%# "~/ProductImageHandler.ashx?Id="+ Eval("Id") %>'`  have null value then i want to display a dummy image from any folder that i will place in project. So how i can do this

```
 <asp:Image ID="imgProduct" Width="200px" runat="server"  CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ItemId")%>' 
ImageUrl='<%# "~/ProductImageHandler.ashx?Id="+ Eval("Id") %>'  CommandName="ViewProductImage"/>
```

**ProductImageHandler.cs file**

```
   public class ProductImageHandler : IHttpHandler
    {

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            int itemID = 0;
            int.TryParse(context.Request.QueryString["Id"].ToString(), out itemID);
            if (itemID > 0)
            {
                context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
                Stream strm = ShowImage(itemID);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                int byteSeq = strm.Read(buffer, 0, 4096);

                while (byteSeq > 0)
                {
                    context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, byteSeq);
                    byteSeq = strm.Read(buffer, 0, 4096);
                }
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="Zoneid"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private Stream ShowImage(int itemID)
        {
            WmsItemListDAC _WmsItemListDAC = null;
            DataTable dtProduct = new DataTable();
            if (_WmsItemListDAC == null)
                _WmsItemListDAC = new WmsItemListDAC();
            if (dtProduct == null)
                dtProduct = new DataTable();

            dtProduct = _WmsItemListDAC.GetProductImageByItemID(itemID);
            if (dtProduct.Rows[0]["PICTURE"] != null)
            {
                byte[] image = (byte[])dtProduct.Rows[0]["PICTURE"];
                return new MemoryStream(image);
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that like so:

```
<asp:Image ID="imgProduct" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Convert.ToInt32(Eval("Id")) > 0 ? "~/ProductImageHandler.ashx?Id="+ Eval("Id") : "~/dummy.jpg" %>' />
```

When the `Id` is greater that zero it will set the `ImageUrl` to the handler. If not display a dummy.

If `Id` is not always an integer you can just check for empty strings.

```
<asp:Image ID="imgProduct" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("Id").ToString()) ? "~/ProductImageHandler.ashx?Id="+ Eval("Id") : "~/dummy.jpg" %>' />
```

Comment: i will always have itemid but it is not necessary that every item have image so i want that time a dummy image on this.

Comment: Then what is the problem? If there is no image but a request is always made to `ProductImageHandler.ashx` you can just serve up a dummy from there.